# datetimepicker in MVC3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker

My Datetime picker is working fine for "Html.TextBoxFor" but when i have "Html.EditorFor" it is not showing anydatepicker.

i have a Jquery as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
               $('.dp').datepicker({
                   changeMonth: true,
                   changeYear: true,
                   dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
               });
           });
```

I want to use this function in my .aspx page.

```
 <div class="float-left">
 <%: Html.Label("BAASent Date") %>
 <br />
 <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BAASentDate, new { @class = "dp" }) %>
 <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAASentDate) %>
 </div>
```

for the above code everything works fine.
but when i replace "Html.TextBoxFor" with "Html.EditorFor",it is not displaying any datetime picker.

whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `EditorFor` you probably do not apply the `dp` class to the corresponding input field and so the `$('.dp')` selector that you are using for your deatepicker returns nothing.

One possibility is to apply the class to the parent div:

```
<div class="float-left dp">
    <%= Html.Label("BAASent Date") %>
    <br />
    <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.BAASentDate) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAASentDate) %>
</div>
```

and then adjust your selector so that you fetch the input field that's inside the div with the given classname:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dp :input').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Another possibility is to write a custom editor template for the DateTime field in which you would apply the `dp` class to the TextBox. So inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
    new { @class = "text-box single-line dp" }
) %>
```

and then:

```
<div class="float-left">
    <%= Html.Label("BAASent Date") %>
    <br />
    <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.BAASentDate) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAASentDate) %>
</div>
```

and finally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dp').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Comment: Your second option(creating a  custom editor template) is not working for me.Am i missing anything ?

Comment: and when i apply the class to the parent div,it works fine for "Html.EditorFor".

Comment: I was applying 'dp' class to "Html.EditorFor" also same like "Html.TextBoxFor".                                                                                                                         <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.BAASentDate, new { @class = "dp" })%>.                                                                    but here datetime picker is not working as it used with "Html.TextBoxFor"

Comment: @Santosh, the second argument of the EditorFor helper is not what you think it is. You cannot set CSS styles like that or pass html attributes as you do with a TextBox. What doesn't work with my second approach? Is the editor template rendered correctly? Did you ensure that the name and location is correct: `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx`? At runtime do you get the `dp` class applied to the textbox?

Comment: Yes, the second argument of the EditorFor helper is not taking CSS styles.In the Second approach iam able to render it correctly.there was a problem with location.                                                       Thanks for the help @Darin Dimitrov